# Stop animator changing Y position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animator

I got a problem when using animator in Unity. I want to cast a ray from the position of the character to forward by using

```
Ray ray = new Ray(transform.position, transform.forward);
Physics.Raycast(ray, out hitInfo);
```

But when I check the "Bake Into Pose" in Root Transform Position(Y) the animator(Running and Walking) would change the position and the Y axis would be lower than actual value and become negative. So the ray sometimes could not hit anything. But if I uncheck the "Bake Into Pose" the character would lose gravity. So how should I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

If you always want to raycast at a specific height (y) you could constrain the origin from where you are casting. Replace ? With a float, variable or pre calculated value.

```
Vector3 rayOrigin = transform.position;
rayOrigin.y = ? // locked y

Ray ray = new Ray(rayOrigin, transform.forward);
Physics.Raycast(ray, out hitInfo);
```